# Spring boot Inheritance in request body

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am facing problem in receiving request object which is sub class of my parent class.
I am expecting to receive subclass in my rest call.But it always returns parent class.
So i did some google search.i find that i need to add @JsonSubTypes but i am getting error.
Please any one help.

**Parent class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "apply_filters", schema = "structure")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "filter_type")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MfiFilters.class, name = "MfiFilters"),
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = VfFilters.class, name = "VfFilters")
})
public class Filters{
}
```

**Child class 1**

```
 @Entity
 public class MfiFilters extends Filters {
 }
```

**Error**

```
JSON parse error: Could not resolve type id 'com.nac.pool.select.MfiFilters' 
as a subtype
```

Answer (score 1):

In your json request, you will need a type attribute

```
{
 ...
type = "MfiFilters"
 ...
}
```